# Ubuntu 12.10 virtualhost conflict

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.10

I have two sites on my server. One I access via my IP, **x.x.x.x/site1**. The other is a registered domain name, www.mysite.com.

Initially, I had only my `/etc/apache/sites-available/default` file available but when I tried loading either of the sites above I just got my `/var/www/index.html` output.

I included a new virtualhost for mysite.com with the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Mysite.com only loads when default is disabled but then, **x.x.x.x/site1** doesn't.

So, I enable the default virtualhost which has the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, **x.x.x.x/site1** works but **mysite.com** does not - instead it loads the **/var/www/index.html** page.

I'm confused about what the issue is.

Comment: sites are built on which language.. it helps to give clear answer

Comment: When you load the main website at document root, any url below it will search in the first app. you can have xx.xx/app1 and xx.xx/app2 or mysite.com to main website and site1.mysite.com to other site

Comment: some comment here are saying that with ubuntu 12.10 you have to change default to default.conf  to get your mysite.com works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vhost configuratin for mysite.com you need to add the ServerName directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    […]
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you.